# How is the repeating borders in Google Calendar achieved without images?

Tags: css

I was looking at Google Calendar's CSS and couldn't find any repeating backgrounds or borders. How is the effect achieved?
Reference:
[Google Calendar's repeating borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZY5L.png)

Comment: They seem to be using default border styling on the table only.

Answer (score 0):

You were not looking close enough. There are borders on elements, and it is the established practice for achieving same/similar effects.